# Reverse Proxy issue for .app domain

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have a java application with .com domain. I'm using reverse proxy(apache) for my customers domains to map to their application URL.

For example, My customer domain is http://example.com which is mapped to http://abcd.com/static/123

Everything is working fine for almost a year.

I have changed my application domain from .com to .app and changed the configuration in apache http://example.com which is mapped to http://example.app/static/123.

Everything is working fine but after a week some for my customers started getting 504 gateway time-out. When I cleared the browser cache then it is working fine.

What would be the problem?

My config sample:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName       www.example.com
    ServerAlias      example.com
    LogLevel debug
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /public/static/ http://example.app/public/static/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse /public/static/ http://example.app/public/static/
    ProxyPass / http://example.app/public/123/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600
    Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example.app/public/123/
    ErrorLog logs/aaa_error_log
    TransferLog logs/aaa_access_log
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So you added a reverse proxy for your .com domain to you .app domain? If you get 504 timeouts after 10 minutes, check if the reverse proxy can reliable connect to the Pass-Hosts.

Comment: It worked for 7 days after 7 days started getting 504 error

Comment: So, why did you do that? (Adding a new listener to reverse proxy to itself, instead of just add another listener)

Comment: Because, the old domain expired

Comment: The question means the **technical** part: why you did not just add another listener to you webserver, but added a completely new reverse proxy service, pointing to your websever itself. Which will stop working, when your domain expires. This looks like a unnecessary loop.